# Not sure how to format existing partition from within new Ubuntu 23.10 installer

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 23.10, disk-formatting

I'm trying to perform, from a bootable USB stick, a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10 on my machine whose drive is already partitioned into a root and a home partition.

Ubuntu's installer's manual partitioning table has the column `format` with tick boxes per line for each partition.

A photograph from my phone of the table can be found here:

[image]

However, I for one cannot select any of the partitions for formatting there, neither in the table overview nor in the window for changing a partition.

How can one, in Ubuntu's installer, specify which partitions should be formatted or not?

Comment: hi @Turtle. You should be able to select a partition and richt click change. the There is a format option on the right. Also, You cannot do it if the drives are mounted. Are you booting from a usb stick?

Comment: I'm booting from a USB stick, yes (added the info in the OP). Right-clicking on a partition doesn't elicit a reaction; the window opening after clicking the 'change' button doesn't show a format option.

Comment: Maybe the installer is stuck because it really wants to create an EFI partition, and there's no space left (1GB seems to be what is does when there's room). Alternatively, you can create an EFI partition with the boot,esp flags any size you choose(e.g. 300GB) before the installer runs.